# Pack my ASP.NET MVC pager into NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I've a pager functionality I use in some of my ASP.NET MVC projects. It consists of a couple of classes and interfaces (to generalize approach to paging of different datasources) and `.aspx` or `.chtml` view.

I can put my C# code into NuGet package/library assembly but what to do with view files which can be different for different projects (different pager design, for example)? One approach is to put HTML to HTML helper, written in C#, but I don't like putting bit chunks of html into C# code.

Is it possible to put views to NuGet package or should I use recipe feature?

Answer (score 0):

I've wanted to push the usage of Nuget in MVC apps to reuse MVC apps themselves not just code - views too. I did manage to pack it up but it has like dozens issues and the experience is horrible.

If you have a pager functionality built inside an ASP.NET MVC Web application project then you can just pack it up and it will pick up the Views too. It does become a lot trickier when using DI, when using Areas, when using localization (resource files don't get picked up). For instance, Area routes might get compiled and included, on the other hand the main global.asax.cs will never be included in the package (so you have to manually copy the routes over if you have them in there).

But it does include stylesheets, so you can style your pager to the default stylesheet which you include in your package and that way you have also solved the issue of design modifications.

But all in all NuGet isn't best suited to pack MVC (or classic ASP.NET webforms) apps.